# cant fix a logical error in a recursion function

Tags: c

If post fix decrement(`--x`) is equal to (`x-1`) so why when I change `factorial(n-1)` to `factorial(--n)`it gives me a logical error of `output = 0`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial (int n) {
    int fact=1;
    if (n>=1) {
        fact=n*factorial(n-1);
    }
    return fact;
}

void main (void) {
    int x , y ;
    printf("Please Enter a Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    y=factorial(x);
    printf("Factorial = %d ",y);
}
```

Comment: "If post fix decrement(--x) is equal to (x-1)" It is not. `x-1` does not change `x`, while `--x` does. The value these expressions evaluate to, are equal but not the whole behaviour

Comment: `--x` is a ***pre***-fix decrement, not a post fix.  And, `--x` is equal to the entire statement `x = x-1;`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior . If you use `--n` you cannot rely on any evaluation order in `n * factorial (--n)`. You can only be sure that `--n` is evaluated before calling the function but you cannot be sure if `n` or `--n` is evaluated first.

Comment: Suppose you had the code `n*factorial(--n)`, and before this line, `n` was equal to `1`. Step by step, what do you think should happen at this point? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that

```
factorial(--n)
```

changes the value of `n` while

```
factorial(n-1)
```

doesn't change the value of `n`

Further, code like

```
fact=n*factorial(--n);
```

has undefined bahavior as it both uses and changes `n` in the same statement (i.e. without a sequence point in between).

For this part:

> If post fix decrement(--x) is equal to (x-1)

1. `--x` isn't post-fix. It's pre-fix
2. They are not equal! `--x` changes the value of `x` while `x-1` doesn't

Answer (score 3):

Making that change:

```
fact=n*factorial(--n);
```

Results in an expression which both reads and writes `n` without an intervening sequence point, which triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> factorial(n-1) to factorial(--n)it gives me a logical error of output
> = 0

It is undefined by C language standard.

But probable explanation of the observable behaviour is: if `n == 1` then

```
fact=n*factorial(--n);
```

`n` will become **zero** before calling factorial. So if `n == 1` then it will become

```
fact=0*factorial(0);
```

Which is always `0`.

Comment: The behavior of `n*factorial(--n)` is not defined by the C standard. `n` **may** become zero before it is used for the left operand of `*`, and that is likely what OP is experiencing, but it should be stated that the behavior is not defined, not that “`n` **will** become” anything.